# stdout prints nothing while running in a remote host

Tags: python

Am new Python Could anyone help me with the following code,

```py
def func_1():
    Servername = input("Enter server IP or Hostname: ")
    Username = input("EnterUID with root privilages: ")
    Password = input("EnterPASWD: ")
    type(Servername)
    type(Username)
    type(Password)
    remotefile1='Remot1.py'
    remotefile2='remot2.yml'
        #SSH Connect host
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(Servername, port=22, username=Username, password=Password)
    remote = client.invoke_shell()
        # Setup sftp connection and transmit this script
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    sftp.put(remotefile1, '/tmp/Remot1.py')
    sftp.put(remotefile2, '/tmp/remot2.yml')
    sftp.close()
    stdout = client.exec_command('python /tmp/Remot1.py')[1]
    for line in stdout:
        print (line)
    client.close()
    return
```

In the above code I transfer two files `Remot1` and `remot2` to a remote to a Linux machine from a Windows machine. Then using

```
client.exec_command('python /tmp/Remot.py')[1]
```

I run the remote Python code and print `stdout`; but I see blank content in Windows PC `stdout` prints nothing..

**Remot1.py:**

```py
import sys
import time
import os
import cmd
import datetime
import yaml
import subprocess, shlex
import requests
import socket

with open("remot2.yml", 'r') as stream:
        out = yaml.load(stream)
        print 'versionon is :'
        v = out['os_bundle']['version']
        x = v.replace(".", "_")
        print x, 'Bundle'
```

Comment: There's no `"remot.yml"` to open.

Comment: Its Remot1.py file,,

Comment: There's still no `"remot.yml"` for `Remot1.py` to open.

Comment: Sorry for typos, When I run the transferred file locally on the remote machine I can see the output...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding get_pty=True, environment=None in to the exec_command

`exec_command('python /tmp/Remot.py', timeout=60, get_pty=True, environment=None)`